# Behavior of ConnectableObservable in RxJava2?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm using an `Observable myObs` that emits one and only one item, and never completes. I want to share that item to multiple `Subscriber`s at various times.

`.replay(1)` will transform the source to a `ConnectableObservable`. So I should be able to "preload" the cache and receive a Disposable with:

```
ConnectableObservable myConnObs = myObs.replay(1);
Disposable mainDisposable = myConnObs.connect();
```

Once this is done (or even before it), any number of `Subscriber`s should be able to receive the sole item with

```
Disposable subDisp1 = myConnObs.subscribe(); 
Disposable subDisp2 = myConnObs.subscribe();
```

Each of these `Subscriber`s should be able to stop listening by disposing `subDisp1` etc., right? But doing this doesn't break the connection held by `mainDisposable`, right? Disposing it should unsubscribe from `myObs`, regardless of the state of the "sub-subscriptions", right? What happens to active `Subscriber`s if `mainDisposable` is disposed? Do they get an error notification or anything (remember that `myObs` never signals Completed)?

Comment: Observers coming and going doesn't affect a `ConnectableObservable`'s connection. Disposing the connection won't signal any events to those observers and generally it is recommended you dispose the observer's connection before disposing the connectable connection. This can be usually achieved by hosting all `Disposable`s in a `CompositeDisposable` and clearing/disposing that

Answer (score 0):

As @akarnokd has explained, Observers coming and going don't affect a ConnectableObservable's connection. Disposing the connection won't signal any events to those observers and generally it is recommended you dispose the observers' connections before disposing the connectable connection. This can be usually achieved by hosting all Disposables in a CompositeDisposable and clearing/disposing that.